Lookup field on standard layout shows extra field when user has no access to the record from the lookup
An opportunity record has lookup to Lead.
When a user can access the lead record, it displays correctly on the layout 
When I log in as a user who doesn't have access to the Lead, the lookup value shows Lookup Name + Lead company. Any idea why it shows an extra field?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry that your question got auto-downvoted. This happens sometimes.
Welcome to the community.
Trying to edit the page will give you more insights than we can from a screenshot. If you are using Lightning Record Pages, look for different fields on the page that may have different visibility conditions.
I recommend the following steps:

Try to go and edit the page, and see if there are any such fields in the Lightning record page that has a visibility condition on it.
If nothing is present like that, then either share your .flexipage XML file for this page (assuming it is Lightning Record Page), or try to open a case with Salesforce Support for help.

Thanks. Hope this helps. And do not mind the downvote much - it is not there to discourage newcomers.
